# Escape asterisk sign in variable in Gitlab ci yml

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

I have a variable declared like this

```
variables:
    SCHEDULE: "35 0 5 * * ?"
```

and it is used here

```
- CMD="python helloworld.py"
- if [ ${SCHEDULE+x} ]; then CMD+=" --schedule ${SCHEDULE}"; fi
```

when this `${SCHEDULE}` variable is used, the asterisks (`*`) are converted into the list of files/directories in that container while I just want this variable to be like it is written.

How can I escape the asterisk * sign in Gitlab CI yml file’s variables?

here is the way the whole command is called:

```
 - CMD="python helloworld.py"
 - if [ "${SCHEDULE+x}" ]; then CMD+=" --schedule \"${SCHEDULE}\""; fi
 - echo $CMD
 - eval $CMD
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in calling the `eval` function.

Updated it to this and it all worked.

```
eval "${CMD}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The yml file isn't the problem; it's the script that gets executed. You need to quote the parameter expansions.

```
 - CMD="python helloworld.py"
 - if [ "${SCHEDULE+x}" ]; then CMD+=" --schedule \"${SCHEDULE}\""; fi
```

You need the quotes in the value of `CMD` as well so that when `CMD` gets executed, you execute

```
python helloworld.py --schedule "35 0 5 * * ?"
```

and not

```
python helloword.py --schedule 35 0 5 * * ?
```

Comment: Thanks @chepner, but it didn't fix. Still the same issue

Comment: How does `CMD` actually get used? Generally, this is not a safe way to build up a command; an array would be preferable, but I don't know if you can assume `bash` will be used to execute the command.

Comment: this is what it returns. The `"` are there but inside is it still the list of all files in that directory

```
python helloworld.py --schedule "35 0 5 helloworld.py development.json helloworld.py development.json ?"
```

Comment: Are you sure `eval` is being used? What you are describing sounds more like `CMD` is simply being expanded in command position, like `$CMD` rather than `eval $CMD` or `eval "$CMD"`.

Comment: let me put the list of commands into the question, so it would look readable.

Comment: The question is updated. This is how I call it.